# Display local time in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In config/application.rb I have "config.time_zone = 'UTC'" (without quotes) in the file.  I am assuming this is to make the conversion from the user's time, which is entered into the view, to UTC, which is stored in the database.  My question is, how do I convert the UTC value from the database to the user's local time to display in the view?  I have read that rails takes care of that automatically - how do I tell it to do this?

I have a timezone field in each user's row in the database, I'm just not sure what to store in there, also.  I know about rake time:zones:all - I just don't know how all of this fits together in rails 3!

Thank you,

sk

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When working in multi-zone environment it's wise to have time zone set to UTC. That's perfectly valid in your application.rb

Rails will automatically transform all time to the **current time zone**, that can be set with

```
Time.zone = "some-zone"
```

What I use is a **before_filter** in ApplicationController where I set the time zone according to the current user. Then all operations works within this zone and you don't need to think about it in your controllers/models/views.

Suppose that you have some model Foo with some datetime field. Then working in the irb console:

```
Time.zone = "Prague"
x = Foo.create(:it_will_happen_at => Time.zone.now)
x.it_will_happen_at # => Sat, 25 Sep 2010 13:45:46 CEST +02:00 

Time.zone = "London"
# it is needed to refresh the field after a time zone has changed.
# In normal situation it'd not be needed, it's just for this console example
x.reload
x.it_will_happen_at # => Sat, 25 Sep 2010 12:44:46 BST +01:00
```

When you take a look into the DB, you'll find that value is Sat, 25 Sep 2010 11:45:46 UTC.

As for the zone value I prefer names of cities as it works smoothly with daylight savings (summer / winter time).

Comment: saved my time!! should've found this earlier.