# Rails UTC displayed date to custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time, utc

I'm sending this to my view:

```
<%= @venue.eventdate %>
```

which displays a UTC date time.
e.g. *2013-01-10 17:15:00 UTC*

I found  [this site for strftime command](http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/) and created a custom built. 
I foolishly added this to end of my object in my view like that:

```
<%= @venue.eventdate.strftime(%A, %e %B %Y at %l:%M %p) %>
```

e.g.(ideally) *Thursday, 3 January 2013 at 4:08 AM*

And of course it didn't work. Anyone know how make the correct conversion in a simple way?

Comment: Don't really know if this is the origin of your problem but you forgot the double quotes : `<%= @venue.eventdate.strftime("%A, %e %B %Y at %l:%M %p") %>`

Answer (score 0):

This is typically handled client side with something like JS given that the client is more aware of it's own locale.

[Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

if you are bent on doing this server side

[Display local time in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793324/display-local-time-in-view)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can create your custom date method. First you create a date_formats.rb file in config/initializers and for example create a time format like this:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:day_month_year] = "%A, %e %B %Y"
```

and use this method in view file like "to_formatted_s(:day_month_year)"

```
<%= object.eventdate.to_formatted_s(:day_month_year)%> <%= object.created_at.strftime("%I:%M %p")%>
```

Do not forget restart rails server after add date_formats.rb file.