# Ruby/Sinatra/erb: get browser time

Tags: ruby, time, sinatra, erb

is it possible to get the browser time?

Because the server runs in ireland so that everyone gets the ireland time when i use`<%= Time.now%>`.

The user should see his time.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3793698/2128691

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display local time in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793324/display-local-time-in-view)

Comment: the anwser in the about links says, that you have to set Time.zone. But i dont know where the user comes from. One can be from usa and from china. The user's timezone should be automatic determined

Comment: Why not use JavaScript on the client side to display time instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837183/displaying-date-time-in-users-timezone-on-client-side